# Specific label layout

Tags: qgis, labeling

Currently, I have this basic label layout :
[image]

But I would like this kind of layout :
[image]

I did not find how to do this (and if it's possible).

Please help me if you know how to do it.

Comment: Did you check the documentation of QGIS, e.g. https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html?highlight=callout#callouts-tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from QGIS 3.10 you can use [Label Callouts](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/index.html#feature-label-callouts) to indicate a line when moving labels.

As indicated in @[eurojam](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87346/eurojam)'s comment, you need to enable Draw lines under the [Callouts tab](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html?highlight=callout#callouts-tab) to show a line when moving a label.

When you click the `Move` label icon located on the `Label toolbar` and select the label you want to move, you will be prompted to select a field that will be used as the primary key, you can select any unique field. In the example case, I used the `NAME` field:

[image]

After that, you can start moving the labels you want and lines will be drawn for those labels.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

If you want to know where the labels x and y are located, they are located under the `Layer Properties → Auxiliary Tab`

[image]

You can remove those callouts by clicking the `red minus` to delete the callouts and start again.